# How to retain multiindex in pandas dataframe while concatenate two separate dataframe

Tags: pandas, multi-index

[image]

dfs_subs dataframe contain multiindex one level is Question-0 and next level is (Score,..)
and i have other dataframe which is having only one level.When i am doing
table_1 = pd.concat([df_metadata, dfs_subs], axis=1, levels=0)

table_1 output is showing like below

[image]

but i want Question-0 should be one separate level instead of combined as one single column.

For example:

[image]

Comment: What is `print (df_metadata.columns[:5].tolist())` and `print (dfs_subs[:5].tolist())` ?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  

df_metadata.columns[:5].tolist()) = ['id', 'FriendlyName', 'CreatedDate', 'AuditorId', 'EmployeeId']
(dfs_subs[:5].tolist())

 [('Question-0',
  ('Score',
   'InitialScoreOfQuestion',
   'NotApplicable',
   'FeedbackCommentQuestion',
   'PresetCommentQuestion',
   'MechanicsFeedBack',
   0)),
 ('Question-1',
  ('Score',
   'InitialScoreOfQuestion',
   'NotApplicable',
   'FeedbackCommentQuestion',
   'PresetCommentQuestion',
   'MechanicsFeedBack',
   1)),
 ......

Comment: Can you add it to question by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67057684/edit) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need `MultiIndex` in both is possible add empty values for second level for `MultiIndex` in both `DataFrame`s:

```
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, ['']])
print (df1)
  Name Age
          
0  Sam  43

#check how looks MultiIndex converted to list
print (df1.columns.tolist())
[('Name', ''), ('Age', '')]
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print (df)
  Name Age Address  Fav
             score Time
0  Sam  43       7   10

#check how looks MultiIndex converted to list
print (df.columns.tolist())
[('Name', ''), ('Age', ''), ('Address', 'score'), ('Fav', 'Time')]
```

Comment: Okay.Can you tell me is it possible to do multiindex to a subset of dataframe.I was trying this approach but its not working.I want to apply multiindex to only few columns headers instead of all headers in dataframe.

Comment: @SaswatRay - hmm, I see it now. Problem is `[('Question-0', ('Score', 'InitialScoreOfQuestion', 'NotApplicable', 'FeedbackCommentQuestion', 'PresetCommentQuestion', 'MechanicsFeedBack', 0)), ('Question-1', ('Score', 'InitialScoreOfQuestion', 'NotApplicable', 'FeedbackCommentQuestion', 'PresetCommentQuestion', 'MechanicsFeedBack', 1)),` is not `MultiIndex`, it is column of tuples. How was created?

Comment: Btw, what is expected ouput?

Comment: @SaswatRay - Hmm, I think main question is simple - need MultiIndex? If not, try remove it some way.

Comment: for ex. 
Input :
df1 = 
Name  Age
Sam   43

df2=
Address    Fav
score        Time 

7                  10

Desired output:
Name   Age    Address    Fav
              score      Time 

Sam     43      7           10

Note: Address and score are two multiindex so as Fav and Time

Comment: @SaswatRay - Is possible add it to question? Because bad format in comments

Comment: Sorry, I have added to question.Hope it clear now?

Comment: @SaswatRay - Sure, check last part my answer with `EDIT.`

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. It solved my issue.I could have directly put that sample last picture instead taking much time of yours.Thank you again.